# Unable to set property for ListBox ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

```
List<Post>[] Postok;

public List<Post>[] MyProperty
{
    get { return Postok; } 
    set { Postok = value; } 
}

[DataContract]
public class Post
{
    [DataMember]
    public string _imageSourc { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string _author { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string _maintext { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string _altext { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string _href { get; set; }
}

<ListBox x:Name="sdemotivalo" ItemsSource="{Binding MyProperty[0]}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=_imageSourc}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I want to set MyProperty[0] for ListBox. But it doesnt show anything. I have searched the answer for this problem, but I didnt found it. If u know pls help me.

Comment: Why do you use an array of lists (=list of list)? I think you only need a list... remove []

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `DataContext` for your control or form.  You'd likely do it on the root like so:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding MyClass}">
```

This is assuming that `MyProperty` belongs to an instance of a class called `MyClass`.  Then you can get at the members of `MyClass`, including `MyProperty`.  You would then set `ItemsSource` for your `ListBox` like so:

```
<ListBox x:Name="sdemotivalo" ItemsSource="{Binding MyProperty[0]}" >
```

The first line above tells your form to look at `MyClass` to get its data.  Thus when you say `ItemsSource="{Binding MyProperty[0]}"`, you're saying, "look at the class instance you're bound to (`MyClass`) and find a property called `MyProperty`", from which point you can then index into `MyProperty` and get what you want.

I am curious though why you're using an array of `List<T>` - I'm not sure I've ever seen that.

Comment: <ListBox x:Name="sdemotivalo" ItemsSource="{Binding MyProperty[0]}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=_imageSourc}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>

Is it ok? 'couse the listbox doesnt show anything

Comment: How are you setting your `DataContext`?

Comment: <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" DataContext="{Binding MainPage}">

Comment: Don't try and bind directly to your `xaml.cs` file.  Create a class of some sort to hold `MyProperty` and create an instance of that class to use as your `DataContext`.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the Public property is MyProperty and you are binding to ListProp.  Post the code where you initialize Postok and assign values.